# Bug in the Newsletter Subscription form

Tags: bug, email-notification, newsletter, subscription

I found a small bug in the newsletter subscription form on the Stack Exchange platform.

Steps to reproduce it:

1. In the "Preferences" tab, check in the "Newsletter" section "Send me the weekly newsletter." The disabled button "Save newsletter settings" becomes enabled.
2. Click on the link "Manage newsletter subscriptions." The "subscriptions" page for the user appears.
3. Due to the fact there was not really anything to do, I clicked the browser Back button.
4. And here comes the bug: The checkbox "Send me the weekly newsletter" is still checked - as selected before - **but** the button "Save newsletter settings" is disabled.
5. Unchecking "Send me the weekly newsletter" enables the button "Save newsletter settings." But remember - the setting has **not** been saved. You can easily confirm this clicking on the "Preferences" link again.
6. Finally, to save the weekly newsletter setting,  you have to click one more time on the "Preferences" link, check "Send me the weekly newsletter" and click on the "Save newsletter" settings.